# ActiveAdmin -- How to access instance variables from partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I can't seem to access instance objects in partials. Example:

In controller I have:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Store do
  sidebar "Aliases", :only => :edit do
    @aliases = Alias.where("store_id = ?", params[:id])
    render :partial => "store_aliases"
  end
end
```

Then in the _store_aliases.html.erb partial I have:

```
<% @aliases.each do |alias| %>
  <li><%= alias.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

This doesn't work. The only thing that does work (which is horrible to do as I'm putting logic in a view is this:

```
  <% @aliases = Alias.where("store_id = ?", params[:id]) %> 
  <% @aliases.each do |alias| %>
     <li><%= alias.name %></li>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: It's horrible to use a for-loop in Ruby :(

Comment: sorry, i have the .each in actual code but for some reason ended up typing for here! :) (damn php background)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When rendering a partial you need to actively define the variables that are given to that partial. Change your line

```
render :partial => "store_aliases"
```

to

```
render :partial => "store_aliases", :locals => {:aliases => @aliases }
```

Inside your partial the variables is then accessible as a local variable (not an instance variable!). You need to adjust your logic inside the partial by removing the `@`.

```
<% aliases.each do |alias| %>
  <li><%= alias.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

For further reading have a look at the [API documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) (specifically the section "3.3.4 Passing Local Variables").

Answer (score 12):

You have to pass your instance variable to your partial in order to use it there:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Store do
  sidebar "Aliases", :only => :edit do
    @aliases = Alias.where("store_id = ?", params[:id])
    render :partial => "store_aliases", :locals => { :aliases => @aliases }
  end 
end
```

Then in your partial you will be able to use it as local variable

```
<% aliases.each do |alias| %>
  <li><%= alias.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Technically you got in first here (albeit 1 sec). Bummer you didn't get the kudos. I've given you an up vote ;)